# How to declare an array outside function in vue's component syntax

Tags: vue.js

I want to declare a global array inside `vue.js` component, so that I can access it in all the methods. Where do I declare it in which part of component?

I have tried setting in `PROPS` but it produces an object while I need an array type.

```
export default{  
   name:"BarElement",
   props:[  
      "labels",
      "dataset",
      "colors"
   ],
   methods:{  
      drawGraph() {  
         var dataPoints =[]; 
         var dataPoint =this.getDataPoint(upperLeftCornerX,nextX,value); 
         this.dataPoints.push(dataPoint);
      }      
      getDataPoint(x, nextX, value) {  
         return {  
            'leftEdge':x,
            'rightEdge':nextX,
            'value':value
         }
      },
      showToolTip(event) {  
         var mouseX = event.offsetX; 
         var toolTipVal = this.dataPoints.forEach(function(item, key) {  
            if(mouseX >= item.leftEdge && mouseX <= item.leftEdge ) 
            return item.value;
         });     
         console.log(toolTipVal);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare it inside the data object

```
data () {
    myArray:[]
 }
```

You can also declare props as an object, as this will allow to specify the type of the props

```
props: {
  labels: Array,
  dataset: Array,
  colors: Object
}
```

If you want all your components of that type to share the same array, declare it outside of the export default statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Inside your component you can declare with data as function and that will be locally to your function.

```
name: "BarElement",
props: ["labels", "dataset", "colors"],
data: function() {
    return {
        foo: {
            text: 'text1'
        }
    }
}
```

In case If you want to declare a global array in your app component.

Similar to the component, you can able to add the data inside it.

Now, to access that data, you can use it with `this.$root.[nameOfObject]`.

Here are the official docs for [$root](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#vm-root)

Hope this helps!